# Adding Content to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently using this code to get content from a page on button click:

```
function getfilter(str){
  $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
        //path to  php page to get  data
    url:"getreceipt.php?table="+str+"",
    success:function(html){

      //here is your success action
      //get data on div  
        $("#receipt").html(html);
    }
    });
 }
```

I then would like to use this code to add the innerHTML content to the same div above the content the previous code created:

```
function updateCarList(transaction, results) {
    //initialise the listitems variable
    var listitems = "";
    //get the car list holder ul
    var listholder = document.getElementById("receipt");

    //clear cars list ul
    listholder.innerHTML = "Receipt<br>";

    var i;
    //Iterate through the results
    for (i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
        //Get the current row
        var row = results.rows.item(i);

        listholder.innerHTML += "Chair "+row.chair+"-<input type='hidden' id='chair[]' name='chair[]' value='"+row.chair+"' /><input type='hidden' id='item' name='item[]' value='"+row.item1+"' /><input type='hidden' id='price' name='price[]' value='"+row.price+"' />" + row.item1 + " - $" + row.price + " (<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='deleteCar(" + row.id + ");'>Delete Car</a>)<br>";
    }

}
```

I've tried multiple ways including appendTo, append, text, html, but nothing seems to work.  The way it stands now it just replaces the code that was fetched from getreceipt.php

could any one offer any advice?  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"append" should work, quit using innerHTML if you are already using JQuery. I would actually create a separate div and append all rows into this div then append this div into the list holder.

```
... // your code above
//Iterate through the results
var chairs = $('<div></div>');
for (i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
    var row = results.rows.item(i);
    var rowHTML = "<p>Chair "+row.chair+"-<input type='hidden' id='chair[]' name='chair[]' value='"+row.chair+"' /><input type='hidden' id='item' name='item[]' value='"+row.item1+"' /><input type='hidden' id='price' name='price[]' value='"+row.price+"' />" + row.item1 + " - $" + row.price + " (<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='deleteCar(" + row.id + ");'>Delete Car</a>)</p>";
    chairs.append(rowHTML); 
}
listholder.append(chairs);
... // your code - actually only function closing.
```